# Setting up users with remote database

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication

I have a remote database (running Postgres) and want to set up a user scheme.

Each facility registered to use the software will initially receive login credentials for an administrator, who will then create users for his facility. Each user will have certain access privileges to certain areas of the software (for example, some menus will not be available to lower level users).

In addition, each facility will be licensed to have a limited number of simultaneous connections to the database (seems to me that this would mean each facility would receive a single Postgres username/password with a maximum number of connections).

I can see several options, none being optimal.

1. Each user will have to log in using four fields - username/password for facility, and username/password for user. (seems excessive to have four log in fields)
2. Each user will log in using a username/password for their user with the username/password for facility hardcoded into the program (causes the headache of having to have different versions of the software for each facility, but the added security that they can't ever use their program to access another facility's data).
3. Write data to a file somewhere on the computer that contains a portion of the login information (needs to be encrypted, I would guess) that is read on startup (seems insecure to some extent even if encrypted).

How is this typically structured?

Comment: By the way, I am referring to a desktop application accessing a remote Postgres database, currently set up with data from multiple facilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far your best bet will be to avoid setting a hard limit on the number of clients. Allow some flex, and do periodic reporting queries against `pg_stat_activity` to see if anyone's consistently overrunning their limits. Deal with it via non-technical means if they are. You can use `pg_has_role` etc to group logged in users by company roles in order to monitor connection limits per-company.

That way, your clients don't have to panic when a machine crashes and they have to wait ages for a TCP/IP timeout before they can reuse the connection. etc.

PostgreSQL does not support enforcing a connection limit on members of a non-login role. So you can't create a role, set a connection limit, and GRANT that role to users in order to limit the total connections by members of that role. Nor does it have ON LOGIN triggers.

If you absolutely had to do enforce per-group login counts, I think you'd have to use a C-level trigger to implement your connection limiting.

If you could restrict `SET ROLE` or `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` so it would require the user to supply a password, you could give the company a single `LOGIN` role with a connection limit. The account would have no access privileges beyond login. Then you'd have each user `SET ROLE` to their personal account. However, as PostgreSQL doesn't offer any way to password restrict `SET ROLE` / `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` this isn't going to work unless you trust your users, in which case you generally won't have separate users/passwords in this situation anyway.

You ask "how is this typically structured" ... but it typically isn't done at all. At most, you'd use per-user limits. So you're trying to do something a bit unusual, and poorly supported.

Comment: Still confused about how to handle users though. The easiest method seems to have a database login and then maintain a user table within the database. I know it requires a two phase log in (log into the database, log in as user). I was trying to avoid this, but every other method just seems to get too complicated.

Is it common to have this type of authentication?